# dd macOS disk – encrypted after dd

Tags: backup, disk-utility, encryption, filevault

I am trying to clone a regular macOS disk (iMac to MacBook – MacBook connected in disk mode) with APFS (not encrypted or something). For this I am using dd to clone the whole disk. Strange is, that after dd is complete (disk are exactly same size) I try to boot the MacBook is just displays the Ventura screen (without loading Ventura) with my avatar and name and prompt to password. But my password do not work. If I open recovery mode and check the **disk on MacBook the APFS seems encrypted** – but the original ones are not encrypted.

The iMac has T2 chip (but securities disabled in recovery mode), the destination (MacBook) has no T2 chip.

Any idea why this is happening? The device identifiers are for sure the same since the whole disk get cloned. Now I am trying to dd within the original macOS on iMac. Maybe this changes anything – but would not understand why.

Or do I need to clone with ASR tool from apple? Maybe try to recover from disk utility in macOS – will check that.